# Are the terms 'measure' and 'function' used interchangeably?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

I am reading a paper, but it seems to me that the author uses the terms 'measure' and 'function' interchangeably. For example,

> Let us consider a bounded measure $\mu$ so that the measure $(1 + \vert x \vert)\mu$ is also bounded. If moreover **$\mu $ belongs to $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^2)$**, then a unique divergence free vector filed $v$ belonging to $\sigma + L^2(\mathbb{R}^2; \mathbb{R}^2)$ for some stationary smooth vector field $\sigma$ exists so that $\omega(v) = \mu$.

Also, vice versa

> Assume that $v_0$ belongs to $E_m $ and that the singular part (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) of $\omega_0$ is a positive measure.

where $E_m = \sigma + L^2(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\sigma$ is a smooth vector field.

I am wondering if measure and function are used interchangeably by abuse of notation. I haven't read a book where it says about this explicitly. If so, then is the function a Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to the Lebesgue measure? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Where in the quotes did the author mention "function"?

Comment: I think it's better to identify functions as a subset of measures (at least when working on a space that admits something like Lebesgue measure), where you identify a (nice enough, say positive measurable or $L^1$) function with the measure with that density. Not all measure are functions, e.g. the Dirac mass at 0 doesn't have a density w/r/t Lebesgue measure. But all (nice enough) functions are measures.

Comment: @Creator No, he didn't mention 'function'. Based on the fact that $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a function space, I assume that he thinks of the measure $\mu$ as a function.

Comment: ok. @PhysicalMathematics gives the perfect comment.

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics Thank you for your comment! So, can I ask if it is a sort of a tacit custom?

Comment: Definitely is standard terminology in certain areas. Very often if you can embed a simpler object in a more general object, you identify the simple object with its embedding. I.e. we think of $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, even though when we first introduce $\mathbb{N}$, we don't introduce them as complex numbers, but they do have an isomorphic copy in $\mathbb{C}$, so it is often convenient to think of them as the same. We are doing the exact same thing here.